# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - SignalR How to join a group and send message from the server?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have a set up a basic solution for SignalR where I can send and receive messages to all clients through the browser.

Required solution:

I need to implement the use of groups, BUT with the ability to join the group and send a message from a background service class that is running on the server.

Currently I have only been successful in sending a message to ALL clients from the server.

My background service class (basically a comms server) will be running multiple instances, so each instance will have a unique name such as CommsServer 1, CommsServer 2 etc. Each instance of the comms server will need to output messages to a specific SignalR group of recipients.

In the browser, the user will select which SignalR group they wish to join from a dropdown list that is pulled from the server. The server also has knowledge of this same list and therefore each comms server instance will represent an item from the list.

My code so far:

MessageHub Class:

```
 public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessageToAll(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
 }
```

Message.js File:

```
 "use strict";

 var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/messages")
.build();

 connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = msg + "<hr/>";
document.getElementById("messages").appendChild(div);
});

 connection.start().catch(function (err) {
return console.error(err.toString());
});

 document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
connection.invoke("SendMessageToAll", message).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Razor Page:

```
 <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
 <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
 <div id="messages"></div>

 <script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
 <script src="~/js/message.js"></script>
```

Comms server class:

```
 public class TcpServer
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MessageHub> _hubContext;

    public TcpServerTcpServer(IHubContext<MessageHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public string inboundIpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    public int inboundLocalPortNumber = 10001;

    public void TcpServerIN(string serverName)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            IPAddress localAddrIN = IPAddress.Parse(inboundIpAddress);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAddrIN, inboundLocalPortNumber);

            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); // Networkstream is used to send/receive messages

                //Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[4096];

                String data = null;
                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                    _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync(data);

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, data.Length);
                }
                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need to select a specific SignalR group name e.g. "CommsServer 1" this will form the name of the SignalR group that the user can select from a dropdown list in the browser so they can monitor events from just this one particular server instance. Other user may wish to monitor events from a different server instance.

One option I was considering is simply send events from all servers instances to ALL browser connected clients and then somehow filter the events on the client side, but this would seem an inefficient way of handling things and not good for network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your client to decide which group to join (by selecting from a list of dropdowns), then your client should probably notify the server of its subscription to messages aimed at the group via the hub:

Hub:

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessageToAll(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public async Task Subscribe(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
}
```

Background service:

```
public class TcpServer
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MessageHub> _hubContext;
    private readonly string _serviceInstanceName;

    public TcpServerTcpServer(IHubContext<MessageHub> hubContext, string serviceInstanceName)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _serviceInstanceName = serviceInstanceName;
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToGroup(string message)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.Group(_serviceInstanceName).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your client, perhaps after user chooses an option from your dropdown:

```
connection.invoke("subscribe", "CommsServer 1, or whatever").catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your last method "connection.invoke..." The key requirement for me here is to be able to send a message to the group from the server, not from another browser. It seems the line: "await _hubContext.Clients.Group(_serviceInstanceName).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);"  is what might do this, but having tested the above it's still not working for me. thx

Comment: Ah I've just figured something out, OK yes I think I got it now, many thanks for your help :)

Comment: When i send a message to a group it does not do anything, even tough I registered with await _hubContext.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, Constants.Roles.Admin) and then sent a message with await _hubContext.Clients.Groups("stringHere").SendAsync("Case", obj1, obj2); and then sent it with